# Handling Key Press Events in C#

Tags: c#

I am developing an application in C#. Whenever someone presses keys like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> etc, i want the application to capture them and perform some action based on the key combination that is pressed.

What is the way of achieving that ?

Comment: What kind of application is it? A console app, WPF, Windows Forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for the windows application and want capture event on the windows form you can check this : [How to capture shortcut keys in Visual Studio .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839201)